# __NSCFConstantString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uicollectionview

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    [self.collect registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

    CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];



    NSMutableArray *data = [arr_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.lbl setText:cellData];

    return cell;


}
```

It's crashing , and it's producing the mentioned ERROR. I've compiled it and it's crashing on

```
 NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

statement. Please Help, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `object` `obtained` from `array` is `string` or `array` like using `isKindOfClass`

#### Here your object is NSString and you are assuming it as a NSArray

Make changes like this:

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    [self.collect registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];

    CollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    id data = [arr_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSMutableArray *arrData = nil;
    if([data isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
       NSLog(@"its string");
    else if([data isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]])
    {
       arrData = (NSMutableArray *)data;
    }
    else
    {
       NSLog(@"its something else %@",data);
    }

    NSString *cellData = @"";
    if(arrData)
       cellData = [arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.lbl setText:cellData];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your code is showing error at  arrData = (NSMutableArray *)

Comment: check now i have made changes

Comment: It's showing "It's String" but still crashing on   NSString *cellData =[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; statement :(

Comment: and Prince make an edit in your code by putting ";" after arrData = (NSMutableArray *)data

Answer (score 0):

You stored `arr_list` in `data` than fetched it from `data` and stored into string.

```
  NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

So its not string type.You've to store it in appropriate type.

Comment: arr_list is array of strings only so I guess it's ok to store it that way OR am I doing something wrong?

Comment: ok than try : 

NSString *cellData =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

Comment: Log [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] value what you get in ?